# Looping to create a new column of counts from specific rows

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to make a new column here in my dataset. I want to pick counts out from the full_name column for the species Stegastes planifrons and make a new column with counts (including transects where the count is 0). I used this code:

```r
Fish1$Stegastes_planifrons <- rep(0, nrow(Fish1))
for (i in 1:nrow(Fish1)) {
  if (Fish1$Full_name[i] == "Stegastes planifrons") {
    Fish1$Stegastes_planifrons[i] == Fish1$count[i]
  }
}
```

EDIT: Data in dput form:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), Location = c("Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", "Tela", 
"Tela"), Site = c("AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", 
"AD", "AD", "AD", "AD"), Depth = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Transect = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Family = c("Pomacentridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Serranidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Acanthuridae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", "Scaridae", 
"Carangidae", "Scaridae", "Labridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", "Scaridae", 
"Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Haemulidae", 
"Lutjanidae", "Scaridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacanthidae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Labridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Labridae", "Chaetodontidae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Labridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", 
"Labridae", "Pomacentridae", "Pomacentridae", "Haemulidae", "Haemulidae", 
"Pomacentridae"), Genus = c("Stegastes", "Anisotremus", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Serranus", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Microspathodon", "Abudefduf", "Microspathodon", 
"Haemulon", "Microspathodon", "Abudefduf", "Acanthurus", "Haemulon", 
"Anisotremus", "Anisotremus", "Sparisoma", "Caranx", "Scarus", 
"Halichoeres", "Scarus", "Sparisoma", "Anisotremus", "Sparisoma", 
"Scarus", "Scarus", "Scarus", "Scarus", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Scarus", "Microspathodon", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Microspathodon", "Microspathodon", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Scarus", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Haemulon", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Anisotremus", "Lutjanus", "Scarus", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Holacanthus", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Halichoeres", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Microspathodon", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Thalassoma", "Chaetodon", 
"Haemulon", "Haemulon", "Stegastes", "Thalassoma", "Stegastes", 
"Stegastes", "Stegastes", "Halichoeres", "Stegastes", "Chromis", 
"Haemulon", "Haemulon", "Stegastes"), Species = c("planifrons", 
"virginicus", "adustus", "partitus", "partitus", "adustus", "partitus", 
"adustus", "adustus", "adustus", "variabilis", "partitus", "adustus", 
"adustus", "tortugarum", "adustus", "partitus", "adustus", "partitus", 
"chrysurus", "saxatilis", "chrysurus", "carbonarium", "chrysurus", 
"saxatilis", "coeruleus", "chrysargyreum", "virginicus", "virginicus", 
"viride", "ruber", "vetula", "bivittatus", "iseri", "viride", 
"virginicus", "viride", "iseri", "iseri", "iseri", "vetula", 
"partitus", "adustus", "adustus", "adustus", "iseri", "chrysurus", 
"adustus", "adustus", "chrysurus", "chrysurus", "adustus", "adustus", 
"iseri", "diencaeus", "adustus", "sciurus", "adustus", "adustus", 
"virginicus", "mahogoni", "vetula", "partitus", "adustus", "tricolor", 
"partitus", "adustus", "adustus", "partitus", "partitus", "maculipinna", 
"partitus", "variabilis", "chrysurus", "adustus", "variabilis", 
"adustus", "partitus", "adustus", "adustus", "partitus", "adustus", 
"adustus", "diencaeus", "partitus", "bifasciatum", "capistratus", 
"carbonarium", "carbonarium", "adustus", "bifasciatum", "adustus", 
"partitus", "diencaeus", "bivittatus", "adustus", "insolata", 
"sciurus", "carbonarium", "adustus"), Full_name = c("Stegastes planifrons", 
"Anisotremus virginicus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes variabilis", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Serranus tortugarum", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Microspathodon chrysurus", "Abudefduf saxatilis", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Haemulon carbonarium", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Abudefduf saxatilis", 
"Acanthurus coeruleus", "Haemulon chrysargyreum", "Anisotremus virginicus", 
"Anisotremus virginicus", "Sparisoma viride", "Caranx ruber", 
"Scarus vetula", "Halichoeres bivittatus", "Scarus iseri", "Sparisoma viride", 
"Anisotremus virginicus", "Sparisoma viride", "Scarus iseri", 
"Scarus iseri", "Scarus iseri", "Scarus vetula", "Stegastes partitus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Scarus iseri", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Microspathodon chrysurus", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", "Scarus iseri", "Stegastes diencaeus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Haemulon sciurus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Anisotremus virginicus", "Lutjanus mahogoni", 
"Scarus vetula", "Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Holacanthus tricolor", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes partitus", "Halichoeres maculipinna", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes variabilis", "Microspathodon chrysurus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes variabilis", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes adustus", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes diencaeus", "Stegastes partitus", "Thalassoma bifasciatum", 
"Chaetodon capistratus", "Haemulon carbonarium", "Haemulon carbonarium", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Thalassoma bifasciatum", "Stegastes adustus", 
"Stegastes partitus", "Stegastes diencaeus", "Halichoeres bivittatus", 
"Stegastes adustus", "Chromis insolata", "Haemulon sciurus", 
"Haemulon carbonarium", "Stegastes adustus"), Guild = c("Omnivore", 
"Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Omnivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Planktivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", 
"Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", 
"Invertivore", "Invertivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Carnivore", 
"Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Carnivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", 
"Herbivore", "Omnivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Omnivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", 
"Invertivore", "Invertivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", 
"Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Herbivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore", 
"Planktivore", "Invertivore", "Invertivore", "Herbivore"), count = c(13, 
4, 41, 10, 10, 41, 10, 41, 41, 41, 2, 10, 41, 41, 2, 41, 10, 
41, 10, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 40, 40, 40, 6, 6, 40, 40, 6, 6, 40, 40, 6, 1, 
40, 1, 40, 40, 1, 1, 2, 14, 52, 1, 14, 52, 52, 14, 14, 1, 14, 
5, 4, 52, 5, 52, 14, 52, 52, 14, 52, 52, 2, 14, 2, 2, 3, 3, 52, 
2, 52, 14, 2, 1, 52, 1, 2, 3, 52), `Transect ID` = c("2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", "2019_Tela_AD_1_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_2_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_2_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", 
"2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10", "2019_Tela_AD_3_10"
), Stegastes_planifrons = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 110L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hi @Bill_marinestats98, please share the result of `dput(Fish1)` in order for us to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: You could try something like: `library(dplyr); Fish1 %>% filter(Full_name == Stegastes_planifrons) %>% group_by(transect) %>% summarize(counts = sum(count))`

Comment: @Skaqqs when I type in dput it gives me an extremely long list of numbers with "L" at the end. The list ends with '(48941L, 48961L, 48962L, 48963L, 48964L, 48965L, 48966L, 48967L, 48968L, 48969L), class = "data.frame")'.

Comment: @Skaqqs I found the code you suggested (dplyr etc etc) gives me
# A tibble: 0 × 2
# … with 2 variables: Transect <dbl>, counts <dbl>

Comment: It looks like you might just need to put `Stegastes_planifrons` in quotes. like: `...filter(Full_name == "Stegastes_planifrons")...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data (I can't extract your data from the image you posted), I can't test/troubleshoot this. The best way to share data is to `dput(Fish1)` and copy/paste the value returned in the console as an edit to your original question. If that is too cumbersome because the dataset is large, you could share a subset of your data or an example dummy dataset. This will get more eyes on your question and will lead to a higher quality answer that's more likely to solve your problem.

Anyways, here is a demonstration of how to summarize counts by group using dplyr. If you still have issues after working through this example, please let me know. I'll help the best I can. Thanks!

```
data(iris)

library(dplyr)

# Dummy transect and count variable for demo
iris$transect <- sample.int(n = 3, size = nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)
iris$count <- iris$Sepal.Length

virginica _counts <- iris %>%
  filter(Species == "virginica") %>%
  group_by(transect) %>%
  summarize(counts = sum(count))

virginica_counts
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   transect counts
#>      <int>  <dbl>
#> 1        1  112. 
#> 2        2  130. 
#> 3        3   87.9

Created on 2022-04-05 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

EDIT

Using your data:

```
Fish1$Transect_ID <- Fish1$`Transect ID`
Fish1 %>%
  group_by(Transect_ID, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  filter(Full_name == "Stegastes planifrons") %>%
  summarize(counts = sum(count))

  Transect_ID       counts
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 2019_Tela_AD_1_10     13
2 2019_Tela_AD_2_10      0
3 2019_Tela_AD_3_10      0
```

EDIT 2

Based on the conversation in the comments, I think this is what you have described:

```
Fish1_Splaniforms <- Fish1 %>%
  group_by(Transect_ID, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(S.planiforms_counts = sum(count[Full_name == "Stegastes planifrons"]))
```

However, if the ultimate plan is for each species to get its own column that indicates counts (of that species) and rows that indicate transects, you could convert from long to wide:

```
library(reshape2)
Fish1$Transect_ID <- Fish1$`Transect ID`
Fish1_wide <- dcast(Fish1, Transect_ID ~ Full_name, value.var="count", fun.aggregate = sum)
head(Fish1_wide)
#>         Transect_ID Abudefduf saxatilis Acanthurus coeruleus
#> 1 2019_Tela_AD_1_10                   6                    1
#> 2 2019_Tela_AD_2_10                   0                    0
#> 3 2019_Tela_AD_3_10                   0                    0
#>   Anisotremus virginicus Caranx ruber Chaetodon capistratus Chromis insolata
#> 1                     16            1                     0                0
#> 2                      1            0                     0                0
#> 3                      0            0                     2                1
#>   Haemulon carbonarium Haemulon chrysargyreum Haemulon sciurus
#> 1                    1                      1                0
#> 2                    0                      0                1
#> 3                    9                      0                2
#>   Halichoeres bivittatus Halichoeres maculipinna Holacanthus tricolor
#> 1                      1                       0                    0
#> 2                      0                       0                    0
#> 3                      1                       1                    1
#>   Lutjanus mahogoni Microspathodon chrysurus Scarus iseri Scarus vetula
#> 1                 0                       12            2             1
#> 2                 1                       18           30             4
#> 3                 0                        4            0             0
#>   Serranus tortugarum Sparisoma viride Stegastes adustus Stegastes diencaeus
#> 1                   2                9               369                   0
#> 2                   0                0               400                   1
#> 3                   0                0               676                   4
#>   Stegastes partitus Stegastes planifrons Stegastes variabilis
#> 1                 60                   13                    2
#> 2                  2                    0                    0
#> 3                126                    0                   10
#>   Thalassoma bifasciatum
#> 1                      0
#> 2                      0
#> 3                      4
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try it and if it doesn't work I'll get a subset of the data

Comment: I have edited original question with data in dput form. Looking at your iris example I see how you have produced the virginica counts but I don't know how you can turn them into a column. I'd want that with counts showing 0 where they are not present in transects if that makes sense? Also, in my data it is best to look at transect ID as this reflects individual transect codes where transect number is actually repetitive in the "Transect" column. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your data with dput! I added an edit to my answer using your data. As an aside, I suggest excluding spaces from names of variables and columns in R to save some typing and potential confusion.

Comment: thanks for this. Unfortunately it seems to have just created a new column for me which is a replicate of "Transect ID" instead of producing a "Stegastes_planifrons" column with counts. Any idea what might have happened? Did you get a new column with the desired counts? Also I'll adjust names....bad housekeeping! Thanks!

Comment: I just tried: 
         'compressed_Fish1$Stegastes_planifrons <- compressed_Fish1 %>%
  group_by(Transect_ID, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  filter(Full_name == "Stegastes planifrons") %>%
  summarize(counts = sum(count))'

This gave error: 
           'Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Stegastes_planifrons, value = list( : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 100' 

as the rows don't match up

Comment: I might not understand exactly what you want. My apologies. See the result from running my code on your data at the bottom of my answer. This is a summary table where rows correspond to transects and counts correspond to the sum of `counts` when `Full_name` is `Stegastes planifrons` occurrences (note there is no underscore for this value in the actual data). Is this the output you are looking for?

Comment: Just saw your previous comment... What is the structure of `compressed_fish1`? The error says that `compressed_fish1` has 100 rows (what do these rows correspond to?) but the summary table of S. planifrons counts only has three rows (where rows correspond to all Transect_IDs in your data).

Comment: Apologies! I see what you've done. So, what I would like is to move these counts into a new column where we'd only have three different values (13, 0, and 0) with lots of repeats. The compressed_fish1 is just the name of the dput I sent you (this is the first 100 rows of my very large dataset!) Each row is corresponds to a certain number a species of fish were/was observed on a particular transect. The count column is that number of fish that were seen.

Comment: Also the dput data I sent you is only the first three transects worth - hence why there would only be three values (repeated) in the new column S.planifrons. Once I have created the new species columns like S. planifrons, and other species from the full_name column I'll delete it so the dataset makes more sense

Comment: I see now. I think you are describing "convert data from long to wide format." I'll post an example of how to do that.

Comment: I added a second edit.

Comment: Thanks so much! Think you've sorted it all for me! Have found an issue with my counts but that's totally separate! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck out there.

Comment: If my answer was adequate, you can mark it as correct and close the question. This makes it easier for future answer-ers to skip, and for future readers to read.